# How to pass information from i number of textboxes through an array to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
@for(var i = 0; i < ViewBag.numassets; i++){
<tr>
    <td>
    @{
        string assetname = ("Assetname"+Convert.ToString(i));
        @Html.TextBox(assetname, "", new { style = "width:150px" });
        namearray[i] = Convert.ToString(Html.TextBox(assetname));
     }
    </td>
```

With this code I create a number of textboxes based on the specified amount by user.

Now I'd like to pass the value of these textboxes (could be many textboxes) as an array or list object upon hitting a Submit button. 
I've got a method in a Model file that is build to deal with arrays so this would be preferable.

The difficulty is with the dynamic textboxes. When I pass Assetname1 for instance it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you name them all the same, they should come in as an array.